# How can I percentage makeup of TRUE from a vector?

Tags: sql, r, data-manipulation

This is the code used to derive the first table in my question.

```
JH %>% group_by(ATT_ID, CAR=="B") %>%
summarize(count = n(), .groups = "drop")
```

| ATT_ID | CAR == "B" | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ONE | FALSE | 1 |
| TWO | TRUE | 1 |
| THREE | TRUE | 3 |
| THREE | FALSE | 5 |
| FOUR | FALSE | 2 |
| FIVE | TRUE | 4 |
| SIX | TRUE | 8 |
| SIX | FALSE | 4 |

**How can I get the table above to look like:**

| ATT_ID | Percentage of "B" |
| --- | --- |
| ONE | 0% |
| TWO | 100% |
| THREE | 37.5% |
| FOUR | 0% |
| FIVE | 100% |
| SIX | 67% |

- Notice how some ID's are seen twice so as to show the presence of both FALSE & TRUE whereas other ID's appear once to showcase the presence of only one or the other.

Thank you

Comment: `JH %>% group_by(ATT_ID) %>% summarize(pct_b = mean(CAR == "B")`

Comment: I updated the post. I meant to post these new tables. I apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(ATT_ID) %>%
  summarize(perc = sprintf("%3.1f%%", 100*sum(Count*`CAR =="B"`)/sum(Count)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  ATT_ID perc  
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 FIVE   100.0%
2 FOUR   0.0%  
3 ONE    0.0%  
4 SIX    66.7% 
5 THREE  37.5% 
6 TWO    100.0%
```

Input:

```
structure(list(ATT_ID = c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "THREE", "FOUR", 
"FIVE", "SIX", "SIX"), `CAR =="B"` = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), Count = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 8, 4)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I posted the correct tables this time. My apologies!

Comment: @Antonio, langtang's code produces the desired output (albeit not in your order, but that's minutiae). The only thing I had to change in this code is replace `\`CAR =="B"\`` with `\`CAR == B\`` (as it is found in your data), but otherwise it executed correctly on your data. If there are problems, you should edit your OP and advise why this code doesn't work.